# Java Regex to find a string which starts with SDPCDR_

Tags: java, regex

what is the regular expression which i should use to match a string which starts with `SDPCDR`
and contains date in the format `20120826` and ends with `.asn` ?

an example string is `SDPCDR_delsdp3a_6091_20120826-042451.asn`

Comment: will you have the number before the underscore of only 4 characters or is it varying? And will you have the string always in the above format?

Comment: the string will always be in same format. and the answer by @sQVe works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
^SDPCDR\w+(\d{8})-\w+.asn$
```

Comment: Why are you putting character classes inside character classes? Might as well use `\w` as `[\w]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
"^SDPCDR.*\\d{8}.*\\.asn$"
```

Pretty generous on the date part, but the string is probably specific enough already to avoid false matches. If you're looking for a substring rather than trying to match the entire string, instead use

```
"SDPCDR.*?\\d{8}.*?\\.asn"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SDPCR_[a-z_]*[0-9]{8,8}-[a-z_]*\\\\.asn
```

Comment: This won't even match the example